# Odd behavior with row_number() analytical function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction here.

See below query.

```
SELECT day_id,month_id,time_id,
row_number() over (partition BY month_id order by day_id ) rn
FROM minute_bars_fact order by month_id, day_Id, time_id
```

Produces output:

```
DAY_ID      MONTH_ID    Time_id rn
02-JAN-11   JAN-2011    1080    1
02-JAN-11   JAN-2011    1081    2
02-JAN-11   JAN-2011    1082    3
02-JAN-11   JAN-2011    1083    4
02-JAN-11   JAN-2011    1084    5
02-JAN-11   JAN-2011    1085    6
02-JAN-11   JAN-2011    1086    7
02-JAN-11   JAN-2011    1087    8
```

My expectation here would be that rn would only be incrementing on each new day.  Obviously that isn't the case.  Am i doing something wrong here?

Edit:

Day is not always the same.

```
02-JAN-11   JAN-2011    1436    357
02-JAN-11   JAN-2011    1437    358
02-JAN-11   JAN-2011    1438    359
02-JAN-11   JAN-2011    1439    360
03-JAN-11   JAN-2011    0   361
03-JAN-11   JAN-2011    1   362
03-JAN-11   JAN-2011    2   363
03-JAN-11   JAN-2011    3   364
```

Comment: Because everything has the same month and `row_number()` [provides a unique](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) number per _partition_ this behaviour is correct. I think you're probably looking for the `rank()` function which will return the same number if the day is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My expectation here would be that rn would only be incrementing on each new day.

No this is incorrect. You would need to use `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK` to achieve this behaviour. Not `ROW_NUMBER`

Comment: Only if DAY_ID doesn't contain a time component, like in the sqlfiddle. Better to use trunc(day_id) to be sure.